# spamassasin unable to read Japanese when it is html encoded

Tags: spam, spamassassin, spam-filter

I would like to block some emails which contains certain Japanese words, but spamassassin fails to detect such words when the email is HTML encoded, for example:

```
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--------------050206070005060005050706
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-2022-JP; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

&#12371;&#12435;&#12395;&#12385;&#12399;&#65281;&#27531;&#24565;&#12394;&=
#12364;&#12425;&#20982;&#22577;&#12364;&#12372;&#12374;&#12356;&#12414;&#=
12377;&#12290;&#25968;&#12534;&#26376;&#21069;&#12289;&#12354;&#12394;...

--------------050206070005060005050706
Content-Type: text/html; charset="ISO-2022-JP"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv=3D"content-type" content=3D"text/html; =
charset=3DISO-2022-JP">
  </head>
  <body bgcolor=3D"#FFFFFF" text=3D"#000000">
    &#12371;&#12435;&#12395;&#12385;&#12399;&#65281;</br>
</br>
&#27531;&#24565;&#12394;&#12364;&#12425;&#20982;&#22577;&#12364;&#12372;&=
#12374;&#12356;&#12414;&#12377;&#12290;</br>
...
  </body>
</html>
--------------050206070005060005050706--
```

Example rule in spamassassin:

```
body     JAP_BAD_1  /残念ながら凶報がございます/
score    JAP_BAD_1  5.0
```

However, when I run the test:

```
spamassassin -D textcat -t spam.test
```

It doesn't show up the match. What do I have to do?

Comment: Any reason to not simply reject *all* mail with numeric html entities in supposedly `text/plain` type parts?

Comment: @anx I'm not sure if doing that may reject authentic messages.

Comment: I'm not really an expert on [ISO-2022-JP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_2022#ISO-2022-JP), but it is my understanding that this encoding uses escape codes while your sample instead uses high-value character codes via HTML entities. Were this Unicode, these would be [Cuneiform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuneiform_(Unicode_block)) signs (starting with `` assuming your font can render that), though `&#65281;` is not defined by Unicode afaict.

Comment: @AdamKatz If you decode the HTML entities, for example, with this [tool](https://mothereff.in/html-entities), you will find that `&#12371;&#12435;&#12395;&#12385;&#12399;&#65281;` is actually `こんにちは！`.

Comment: Hah, I was thinking in hexadecimal. Still, that's not a typical use of ISO-2022-JP by my understanding, since ISO-2022-JP would be filled with escape characters.

Comment: @AdamKatz probably you are right. I'm not familiar with ISO-2022-JP.